# How do you view Trace information in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I'm trying to get Azure Trace logging working.  To make it simple, I've created a stock Web Worker Role using 'New Project/Azure Cloud Service'.  It emits several Trace messages using:

```
Trace.TraceInformation("WorkerRole has been started");
```

I enable Diagnostics and point to an Azure Storage Account like so:

[image]

The service appears to deploy and start, but I can't find the diagnostic information anywhere.  Is this the right way to set it up and, if so, where do I go now to see the messages.  If this isn't the right way, a link to a working example would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the contents of `WADLogsTable` table in the storage account (darkbondtest in your case)? Trace logs are saved in this table.

Comment: I've got a table called 'WADLogsTable' in the Azure storage account, but there's no options on the 'Table Service' tab that allows for viewing or downloading.  How are we supposed to view these tables?

Comment: Oh, I see, you need to download a separate utility for exploring the storage account.  I can see my Trace output now, but it requires a lot of clicks just to see the message.  Is this as good as it gets?